# How to disable the UGUI button component?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I used the

```
GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;
```

to disable the button component, but find the UI gameobject become transparent. And I just want disable the button without changing transparent, just like remove the tick on button component.

Did I use it wrong? Or is there something else to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
```